# Validation failed: Stocks product must exist, Stocks location must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three models -> locations, products and stocks.

Stocks is a join table of locations and products.

When creating a new product i used fields_for to show locations and even though i got it to work, for some reason now it does not seem to work anymore and it gives me the above error.

```
<div class="input-field">
  <%= f.label :product_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<div class="input-field">
  <%= f.label :price %>
  <%= f.text_field :price, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<% if !@edit %>
  <%= f.fields_for :stocks do |ff| %>

    <div class="input-field  margin-top x-4">
      <%= ff.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, :structured_location , {:prompt => "Please Select Locations for Product"}, {multiple: true} %>
      <%= ff.label :locations %>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <%= ff.label :quantity %>
      <%= ff.text_field :quantity %>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <%= ff.label :threshold_quantity %>
      <%= ff.text_field :threshold_quantity %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
<% else %>

      <%= collection_select :product, :location_ids, Location.all, :id, :structured_location , {:prompt => "Please Select Locations for Product"}, {multiple: true} %>


<% end %>

<div class="row margin-top x-4">
  <div class="col s12 center-align">
    <%= f.submit "#{current_page?(new_product_path) ? "Create Product" : "Update Product"}", class: "btn wave-effect pink darken-1 btn-large" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  def index
    @products = Product.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.stocks.build
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    if @product.save!
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully saved..."
      redirect_to products_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong, please check the values you entered"
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name,:price, location_ids: [], stocks_attributes: [:id, :quantity, :threshold_quantity, location_id: []])
  end
end
```

product model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stocks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :locations, :through => :stocks

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stocks
end
```

parameters in rails console

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"l1BFhrdyB2QMO5k3+60GNiPphFfF+DXDGPbUU3V2Op2aekObjgIe13k8uoedmDIEZgIeXPZUeS/0VxQXkKa1Uw==",
>   "product"=>{"name"=>"Soap", "price"=>"10", "location_ids"=>["", "1",
>   "2"], "stocks_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"quantity"=>"100",
>   "threshold_quantity"=>"100"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}

Answer (score 3):

After hours of searching i stumbled upon this post

[BigBinary](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html)

it seems that Rails 5 made belongs_to relationship IDs required by default thats why i had validations failed and i couldn't find anything about it.

simply adding `optional: true` in my stock model worked!

```
class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location, optional: true
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, allow_destroy: true

end
```